# await for promise before give the result as input parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I have two components parent and child

parent is resolving a promise in constructor, child is reveiving the result of the promise as @Input() parameter

child is not receiving the result of the promise in life cicle hook other than afterViewCheck and afterContentCheck, I want to avoid those.

I also want to avoid a shared service containing shared data in behaviorSubject or something like that

so the question is, can I await the promise before construct the template with te result of the promise as an input parameter?

Parent:

```
// html: <app-chil [brands]="brands"></>

brands: Brand[] = []

constructor() {
  this.getBrands()
}

async getBrands() {
  this.brands = await new Promise<Brand[]>(resolve => 
    this.equipmentService.getBrands().subscribe(brands => resolve(brands)))
}
```

child:

```
@Input() brands: Brand[] = []

constructor() { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.brands) // receive brands here
}
```

Comment: You could just do, in the constructor, `this.equipmentService.getBrands().subscribe(brands => this.brands = brands)`...

Comment: You should use a setter on your input this way you could make sure the data is actually being passed to the children. An input wont be updated unless the reference changes

Comment: have you tried to make observable from promise and pass that observable to the child and then use simple interpolation with async pipe? {{received$ | async}} https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: @HereticMonkey the child component is standard, shared by many parents so I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a setter, you dont need to use any life cycle hook and its cleaner.

```
brands: Brand[] = [];

constructor() {
   this.getBrands()
}

async getBrands() {
  this.brands = await new Promise<Brand[]>(resolve => 
    this.equipmentService.getBrands().subscribe(brands => resolve(brands)))
}
```

child:

```
private _brands: Brand[] = [];
@Input() set brands(data: Brand[]) {
    this._brands = data;
    console.log(data);
}

constructor() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make observable from promise and pass that observable to the child and then use simple interpolation with async pipe.

Here goes an example. Read it and adapt it to your app (it's tested as is).

child:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name | async}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: Observable<string[]>;


}
```

parent:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
/* import { from } from 'rxjs'; //import 'from' to convert your promise to observable*/

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hello [name]="name"></hello>`,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = of("angular"); //name = from(yourPromise)
}
```